# Update a html table form using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have created a php program to save books details. As well as i created function to update that saved data.but when i try to edit and save edited data nothing happen. Even any error is not shown by program. I used MySQL database. Please help me to solve this problem. I have mentioned my code below.

Here `displaybook.php` page shows the all books details which i have saved.Edit button also there.

`editbook.php` page contain the update query and save query.

displaybook.php code

```
<form method="POST" action="editbook.php">
    <table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> BOOKID </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Title </th>
                <th style="width:50%" scope="col"> ISBN </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Author Name </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Publisher Name </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Category </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> No of pages </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Published year </th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Price</th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col"> Language </th>
             </tr> 
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <?php
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         ?>
             <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $row['bookid']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['isbn']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['authorname'];?></td> 
                 <td><?php echo $row['publishername'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['category'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['noofpages'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['publishedyear'];?></td> 
                 <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['language'];?></td>
                 <td><button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" value="<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>">Edit </button></td>
                 <td><button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" value="<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?> ">Delete </button></td>
             <?php echo "<tr>";
             }
             ?>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </form>
```

editbook.php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $edit_id = $_POST['edit'];
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Failed to connect to database" . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE bookid='$edit_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
?>
<form name="reg-frm" action="editbook.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Title&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="name" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" placeholder="Title" title="eg:- Ayesha" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>ISBN&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="name2" type="text" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['isbn']; ?>"   placeholder="ISBN" title="eg:- 23478890034477" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Author Name&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="name3" type="text" name="authorname" value="<?php echo $row['authorname']; ?>" pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" placeholder="Author name" title="eg:- Ayesha" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Publisher Name&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="name4" type="text" name="publishername" value="<?php echo $row['publishername']; ?>" pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" placeholder="Publisher name" title="eg:- Ayesha" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Category&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="phone" type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" placeholder="Category" title="eg:- English" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>No of Pages&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="name5" type="text" name="noofpages" value="<?php echo $row['noofpages']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Pubished Year&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input id="phone2" type="text" name="publishedyear" value="<?php echo $row['publishedyear']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Price</td>
                <td><input id="phone3" type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="required"> </span>Language</td>
                <td><input id="name6" type="text" name="language" value="<?php echo $row['language']; ?>" pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" placeholder="Language" title="eg:- Tamil" required/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="save" class="submit-btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
}
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $bookid=$_POST['bookid'];
    $isbn=$_POST['isbn'];
    $authorname=$_POST['authorname'];
    $publishername=$_POST['publishername'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $noofpages=$_POST['noofpages'];
    $year=$_POST['publishedyear'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $language=$_POST['language'];

    $query1 = "UPDATE book SET title='$title',isbn='$isbn',authorname='$authorname',publishername='$publishername',category='$category',noofpages='$noofpages',publishedyear='$year',price='$price',language='$language' WHERE bookid='$bookid'";
    if(mysqli_query( $conn, $query1 )){
        header('location:displaybook.php');
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error ($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is save button ?? for $_POST['save'])

Comment: @romanreign  have edited the code. you can see now the save button also

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` as the first thing in editbook.php to see your vars and go from there

Comment: Are you sure the `UPDATE` query is running? Is it redirecting back to `displaybook.php`?

Comment: By the way, where are you connecting to the database? I mean, I know you might have omitted that part on purpose, but still, are you sure that `$conn` is not null? Maybe something in the `error_log` file? I'm saying this because you never check for the connection when you're saving since the `$_POST['edit']` variable is not set when you send the new form.

Comment: @Zeke yeah $conn is not null

Comment: Ok, and does it redirect you back when saving? Or do you get a blank page maybe? If it redirects you back, it's most likely something with the database, for example, missing information or invalid input data. That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @Zeke when redirect to page nothing changing the bookdisplay.php page...always shows same results.no any error message.

Comment: Then, like I said, it's most likely the database not accepting the input, but this doesn't always send back an error message (which might be your problem). I advise you to properly parse all of your input information and/or try your SQL query out directly on phpMyAdmin using the SQL tab. Also, to use prepared statements.

Comment: @Zeke ok i will try

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for not updating is that the `bookid` value is missing from form `reg-frm` in the `editbook.php` file. It should be included, possibly in the first row of the table as `<input type="hidden" name="bookid" value="<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>" />`: a hidden field that you would not want to update/change.

Otherwise there also seems to be a typo in the `editbook.php` file where it reads:

```
</form>
<?php
}
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
```

It should be reading

```
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
```

without the first bracket.